# Jupyter: ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

While I run the following code in Jupyter notebook:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant("hello world!")

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(a))
```

I got the following error messages:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ac/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ac/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ac/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/ac/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/ac/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, the same code if I run directly through python, it works as expected.

Here is my environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Tensorflow 1.5
- Cuda 9.0
- Cudnn 7
- Nvidia Driver 390.12
- Python 3.6
- Anaconda 3

The issue happens after I recently upgrade the Tensorflow. Before I was using Tensorflow 1.4 with Cuda 8 and Cudnn 6. However, I feel this is more like Jupyter notebook issue than Tensorflow installation.

I also tried other solution like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, no luck. I wonder if the Jupyter using the different library than the avocado environment? Or this issue is caused by some failure installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is following:

First, I installed the Jupyter extension nb_conda via `conda install nb_conda`, which will add the ability to view the current kernel environment in Jupyter. Then I realize the Jupyter doesn't use the correct environment I expected.

Second, install Jupyter under the wanted environment `conda install Jupyter`.

Finally, the Jupyter is running under the environment where calls `jupyter notebook`.

Hope this will help anyone encountered the same issue as I did.